# Requesting solution for laravel 8 project

Tags: laravel, dynamic

I'm an elementary web developer, I'm facing a problem. Please help me solve this. I'm creating both row and column dynamic. for save() is fine. But for update, only name is updated and other item
quantities cannot. Here is my codes.

//for save()

```
public function stockAdd(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = validator(request()->all(), ['stock_name' => 'required']);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator);
            }

            $user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;

            $stock_id = random_int(100000, 999999);

            $stocks = new Stocks();
            $stocks->stock_id = $stock_id;
            $stocks->owner_id = $user_id;
            $stocks->stock_name = request()->stock_name;
            $stocks->my_stock = 0;
            $stocks->disable = 0;
            $stocks->save();
           
           
            $brands = Brands::all();
            $products = Products::all();

            foreach ($brands as $brand){
                
                foreach ($products as $product){
                    if($product['brand_id'] == $brand['id']){
                        $product_id = $product->product_id;

                        $stockitems = new StockItems();
                        $stockitems->stock_id = $stock_id;
                        $stockitems->product_id = $product->product_id;
                        $stockitems->owner_id = $user_id;
                        if(request()->$product_id > 0){
                            $stockitems->count = request()->$product_id; 
                        }else{
                            $stockitems->count = 0; 
                        }
                        
                        $stockitems->save();
                    }
                }
               
            }
              
            return redirect()->back()->with('successAddMsg','Successfully Added');
    }
```

//for update()

```
public function stockUpdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = validator(request()->all(), ['stock_name' => 'required']);
        
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator);
            }

            $stock = Stocks::findOrFail($id);
            $stock->stock_name = request()->stock_name;
            $stock->my_stock = 0;
            $stock->disable = 0;
            $stock->update();

            $brands = Brands::all();
            $products = Products::all();

            foreach ($brands as $brand){
                
                foreach ($products as $product){
                    if($product['brand_id'] == $brand['id']){
                        $product_id = $product->product_id;

                        //dd($product_id);
                        $stockitemitems = DB::table("stock_items")->select("*")->where("owner_id",Auth::user()->user_id)->where("stock_id",$stock->stock_id)->get();
    
                        $stockitems->count = $request->input($product_id); 
                
                        
                        $stockitems->update();
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            
           
            return redirect(route('user.stock-list'))->with('successAddMsg','Successfully Added');
    }
```

The problem shows like this "Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: In your update function, you seem to update the name to `request()->stock_name` but leave the other values hardcoded to `0`. Maybe this is a culprit? It might be necessary to share the model as well if that is not the cause

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where did you define this `$stockitems` variable in the `update` method?

Comment: When you've loaded the Model via `$stock = Stocks::findOrFail($id);`, you don't follow it up with `$stock->update()`; you call `$stock->save()`, the same you do in your Create logic. `->update()` expects an array of attributes, like `->update(['name' => 'whatever'])`, and saves immediately.